# UIViewController bouncing back from pushViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, singleton, pushviewcontroller

Let me give a quick briefing of what I have:

I have a navigationController that could go 3 levels deep.

From the first and the second level I'm able to message

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[PlayerViewController playerSingleton] animated:YES];
```

If I do that from the first level it pushes the PlayerViewController's view with no problem. It slides from the right to the left with no problems.

But, if I try to push from a second level view in navigationController it slides just like the other one but then it slides back!

I've double checked if it was any code explicitly saying this but there's none.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is PlayerViewController a singleton? What are you pushing the second time?

Comment: its a singleton cuz at first I wanted to be accessed by anywhere and keep its variables and other stuff.

And on the second time I'm trying to push the same singleton, running exactly the same code.

Comment: Its like is pops the view when it hits the 3rd level deep.

Comment: Solved, I had a lost -popViewControllerAnimated in my code

Comment: Sounds like a very unorthodox design. If you pushing the same view controller, with exactly the same variables each time - what is the user seeing change? Also sounds like you are coupling your Model to your Controller if you are trying to persist variables in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a lost -popViewControllerAnimated in my code.

Just removed that and it's working again.